# SSMS doesn't record application data

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms-2014

We have azure database for our app,at times it happens that data is not getting inserted in few of tables(That tables contain many number of records) in some specific time, and after 1 hr is restarted automatically.This issue happens after 15-20 days.
Is their any maintenance work from azure happens?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the issue ? How the data gets inserted ? As of now, SSMS is working fine for all of us

Comment: @Jayendran I have updated my comment

Comment: Why don't you try with the [latest SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) ?